# Wlan Problem (detects networks but won't connect)

Tags: wireless, 12.10

So my problem is that I recently put Ubuntu 12.10 as dual boot on my desktop pc. After a few hours of googling I was able to get my D-Link DWA-142 to "work". However, it will only see the networks but won't connect. It did connect to the network once, but dropped after a few minutes. I already did **apt-get upgrade && update**. I am currently tethering via my galaxy s2. If I put on a hotspot via the smartphone, it will connect, but will not have an internet conncetion. Thanks in advance.

```
iwconfig
```

gives:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11g  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:144.5 Mb/s   Sensitivity=-200 dBm  
          RTS thr=2346 B   Fragment thr=2346 B   
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

nm-tool gives:

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ndiswrapper
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:19:5B:55:17:53

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points
```

While trying to connect

```
`sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog`
```

gives me:

```
Dec 31 18:28:19 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning        
Dec 31 18:28:21 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long.        
Dec 31 18:28:21 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]        
Dec 31 18:28:21 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): asking for new secrets    
Dec 31 18:28:21 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.        
Dec 31 18:28:21 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.        
Dec 31 18:28:24 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: get_secret_flags: assertion `is_secret_prop (setting, secret_name, error)' failed       
Dec 31 18:28:24 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...        
Dec 31 18:28:24 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...        
Dec 31 18:28:24 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]        
Dec 31 18:28:24 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...        
Dec 31 18:28:24 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.        
Dec 31 18:28:24 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...        
Dec 31 18:28:24 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]        
Dec 31 18:28:24 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'Wireless connection 1' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.        
Dec 31 18:28:24 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'MG'            
Dec 31 18:28:24 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value    '1'        
Dec 31 18:28:24 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'        
Dec 31 18:28:24 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'        
Dec 31 18:28:24 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.        
Dec 31 18:28:24 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.       
Dec 31 18:28:24 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1        
Dec 31 18:28:29 ToterLaptop kernel: [  621.828627] end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0        
Dec 31 18:28:29 ToterLaptop kernel: [  621.828634] Buffer I/O error on device fd0, logical block 0        
Dec 31 18:28:34 ToterLaptop wpa_supplicant[2258]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:1f:3f:d5:1f:32 (SSID='MG' freq=2412 MHz)        
Dec 31 18:28:37 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating        
Dec 31 18:28:42 ToterLaptop kernel: [  634.000763] end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0        
Dec 31 18:28:42 ToterLaptop kernel: [  634.000771] Buffer I/O error on device fd0, logical block 0        
Dec 31 18:28:47 ToterLaptop wpa_supplicant[2258]: wlan0: Authentication with 00:1f:3f:d5:1f:32 timed out.        
Dec 31 18:28:47 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected        
Dec 31 18:28:48 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning        
Dec 31 18:28:50 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long.        
Dec 31 18:28:50 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]        
Dec 31 18:28:50 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): asking for new secrets        
Dec 31 18:28:50 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.        
Dec 31 18:28:50 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.        
Dec 31 18:28:54 ToterLaptop kernel: [  646.165373] end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0        
Dec 31 18:28:54 ToterLaptop kernel: [  646.165380] Buffer I/O error on device fd0, logical block 0        
Dec 31 18:28:58 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive        
Dec 31 18:29:00 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <warn> No agents were available for this request.        
Dec 31 18:29:00 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets') [60 120 7]        
Dec 31 18:29:00 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> Marking connection 'Wireless connection 1' invalid.        
Dec 31 18:29:00 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'Wireless connection 1'        
Dec 31 18:29:00 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'node') [120 30 0]    
Dec 31 18:29:00 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]        
Dec 31 18:29:03 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'none') [30 20 0]        
Dec 31 18:29:03 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]        
Dec 31 18:29:03 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> (wlan0): taking down device.        
Dec 31 18:29:03 ToterLaptop NetworkManager[731]: <info> WiFi hardware radio set disabled        
Dec 31 18:29:06 ToterLaptop kernel: [  658.337199] end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0       
Dec 31 18:29:06 ToterLaptop kernel: [  658.337206] Buffer I/O error on device fd0, logical block 0        
Dec 31 18:29:18 ToterLaptop kernel: [  670.508660] end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0        
Dec 31 18:29:18 ToterLaptop kernel: [  670.508667] Buffer I/O error on device fd0, logical block 0        
Dec 31 18:29:30 ToterLaptop kernel: [  682.677361] end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0        
Dec 31 18:29:30 ToterLaptop kernel: [  682.677368] Buffer I/O error on device fd0, logical block 0  
Dec 31 18:29:42 ToterLaptop kernel: [  694.845447] end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0    
Dec 31 18:29:42 ToterLaptop kernel: [  694.845453] Buffer I/O error on device fd0, logical block 0    
Dec 31 18:29:55 ToterLaptop kernel: [  707.021368] end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your terminal.

1.sudo rfkill list

This will shows you the services on your system.

2.sudo rfkill unblock all

This will unblock all services if anyone is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed this problem, but only on *one* wifi spot while travelling. It wasn't exactly an Ubuntu/Linux problem, since rebooting to Windows showed almost the exact same behavior.

I was able to get a better connection on an Android, at least it would connect reliably and Wifi would cut out after maybe a few minutes, not a few seconds, as Killer-wireless-card usually did.

My best guess would be one of two things - the wireless driver doesn't have its timeout set correctly (not sure how you would change that except by upgrading to a driver/kernel that fixed that), or there is some type of interference that is affecting your wireless card more than others?